# Does anyone know how to get info from a csv?

Tags: python

Im trying to collect info from a csv file and turn the row values into variables and carry those variables into different def functions finding such variables such as the max of whats inside and basically gather information from the csv.

Comment: use pandas, probably the easiest.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv or `pandas`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, you can use the **csv** module

for example, have the following csv file

```
a,1
b,7
c,5
d,2
e,6
```

```
>>> import csv
>>> filename = "/Users/sunnky/Desktop/test.csv"
>>> d = {}
>>> with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     for k, v in reader:
...             d[k] = v
...
>>> new_d = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda m: m[1])
>>> min, max = new_d[0], new_d[len(new_d)-1]
>>> print(min, max)
('a', '1') ('b', '7')
```

Comment: thank you very much that really helped can I ask how you would do it if you wanted to seperate in different def functions such as having the csv on one def and reading from that to add on to finding max def to min def.